# What does dict[str, dict] mean in a function return value?

Tags: python, return-value, pycharm

I'm seeing this in a documentation snippet from PyCharm.

```
def a_func() 
Inferred type: () -> dict[str, dict]
```

I know that the `->` means 'return value' in a function definition but what does the `dict[str, dict]` part mean?

---

The most simple function which demonstrates this is:

```python
def a_func():
    """Docstring to suppress PEP8 warning."""
    return {'a': {'b': 3}}
```

It is being shown by the *"Autopopup documentation"* setting in *Editor → Code Completion*. With this enabled, while hovering the mouse over the `this()` the above snippet is shown.

Answer (score 7):

A dictionary with string keys and dict values; a dictionary of dictionaries.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is there any documentation on this?

Comment: I can't find any and I can't reproduce this return type documentation in pycharm - I hope I didn't jump the gun. What return value to you expect from do_analyze? Could you also say how you setup pycharm to produce this inferred type comment?

Comment: I have edited my question. Your answer seems mostly correct but I'm just not sure... Is this a PyCharm feature or standard python syntax?

Comment: It's not python syntax, it seems to come from the epytext markup language, which PyCharm is able to recognize.

Comment: See my edited question for an example which shows `dict[str, dict` .

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#typing